# Select top 5 results: PHP/SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select the top 5 results, but whenever adding `order by votes desc limit 5` to this code:

```
$req2 = mysql_query('select id, url, name, description, banner, votes 
                     from topsite 
                     order by votes desc 
                     limit '.$first_message .','.$last_message); 
while($dnn2 = mysql_fetch_array($req2))
```

it won't work. How can I fix it?

Comment: Please dont use the `mysql_` database extensions, it is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
Especially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli_` database extensions,
[and here is some help to decide which to use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: What are the $first_message and $last_message? To get only the top 5, just order by descending order and limit to 5.

Comment: *"it won't work"* please be more specific

Comment: @m02ph3u5, Whenever I refresh the page after adding `order by votes desc limit 5` it will just show a blank page. No errors.

Comment: Maybe you got the *LIMIT* wrong. It's `LIMIT <offset>, <count>`. Look at this example from the docs: `SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html - `$last_message` is most probably not what it should be

Comment: @m02ph3u5 Yes it wrong. He only actually need `LIMIT 5` as all he wants is the TOP5

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the TOP 5 then you only need one limiter like this

Also if you use double quotes around your query you can expand `$variables` automatically, which makes it a lot easier to read and debug.

Also if you want to see the errors produced by the `mysql_` extension you have to look for them

```
$top_5_please = 5;

$req2 = mysql_query("select id, url, name, description, banner, votes 
                     from topsite 
                     order by votes desc 
                     limit $top_5_please"); 

// error check
if ( ! $req2 ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    exit;
}

while($dnn2 = mysql_fetch_array($req2))
```

**FINAL NOTE**

> Please dont use the `mysql_` database extensions, it is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
>   Especially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli_` database extensions,
>   [and here is some help to decide which to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following. Also note that mysql_* functions are deprecated. Use PDO instead.

```
$req2 = mysql_query('select id, url, name, description, banner, votes 
                     from topsite 
                     order by votes desc 
                     limit '.$your_limit .' OFFSET '.$your_offset);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$req2 = mysql_query('select id, url, name, description, banner, votes 
                     from topsite 
                     order by votes desc 
                     limit 5');
```

you can't pass string into limit you have to use integer only in limit

Comment: if you are passing parameter then the parameter also should be integer type and not  concat that as string.

Comment: As the query is a string it does not actually matter about the type of the `$limit` variable as long as it is either an integer or a string that holds an integer i.e. `"5"`

Comment: My comment adressed the answer, not your comment.

Comment: @m02ph3u5 Oh my apologise